# while creating an ios app with in app purchase, i have a query

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

As we all know that once we purchased apple subscription plan from a device with Apple id the same will be resume on other device if have login with that same Apple id.

But here we need that every time the user will login on different device with the same Apple id or different Apple Id, we want's the to user purchase the subscription plan. e.g., If user has purchased 2 Subscriptions then he will be able to use app on two different devices So for that we created multiple subscription products.

Can someone help how we can create multiple products for same functionality So that Apple can approve it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's not very clear what your question is. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Koen i have updated my question please check again.
In short, i do not want user to restore his purchase , he needs to purchase subscription again.
Fore first time will want to show one product and if he logins with same id then we want to show new product.

Answer (score 0):

That would go against Apple's guidelines for allowing users to restore their in app purchases on any new or existing devices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html

> Users restore transactions to maintain access to content they’ve
>   already purchased. For example, when they upgrade to a new phone, they
>   don’t lose all of the items they purchased on the old phone.